# Webscraping when some attributes aren't available for all pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape from a website called knowyourcity.info with many settlements on with information. This is my current loop:

```
for u in urllist:
    response = get(u)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    headers_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'settlement-base-status section text-center')
    names = headers_containers.h2.text
    name.append(names)
    year_established = headers_containers.h3.text
    year.append(year_established)
    headers1_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'col-xs-12 text-center')
    countries = headers1_containers.h4.a.text
    country.append(countries)
    headers2_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ = 'bold-it', id = "population")
    populations = headers2_containers.text
    population.append(populations)
    headers3_containers = html_soup.find('div', class_ ='bold-it', id='sharedTaps')
    tap = headers3_containers.text
    taps.append(tap)
    headers4_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'bold-it')
    toiletSeat_toPerson = headers4_containers[7].text
    toiletsToPerson.append(toiletSeat_toPerson)
```

However, for some settlements some attributes are not available. How do I add to this loop an "if true" statement?

Comment: could you share the url you're trying to scrap from?

Comment: sometimes BeautifulSoup failed to fetch the data. so try Selenium web driver

Comment: Did you try writing `if <the condition you want to check>: <do something else>`? What was the problem when you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip a loop cycle by condition you can use the `continue` keyword.

```
for url in urllist:
    if condition:
        continue
```

Will break the current loop cycle if `condition` is True
and start with the next url in `urllist`